# spring, jdbcTemplate, postgresql - last insert id

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbctemplate

I have:

```
public void addJobs(Jobs jobs) {
        this.getJdbcTemplate().update(sqlAddJobs, new Object[] {jobs.getJobName()});
    }
```

In Postgresql DBI have a table:

```
row_id | jobs
```

row_id is auto increment, how can I got last insert id?

My sql:

```
INSERT INTO jobs (jobs) VALUES (?)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One easy option is to make the query like:

```
"INSERT INTO jobs(jobs) VALUES(?) RETURNING row_id"
```

And execute `int id = getJdbcTemplate().queryForInt(sql)`.

Answer (score 2):

I say the following code:

```
this.getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {jobs.getJobName()},Integer.class);
```

in my case SPRING BOOT 2.2.4.RELEASE with JdbcTemplate I used the code above.